# Paw Authentication Token Issue

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, paw-app

I just starting working on an iOS Swift 3 application that will integrate with a certain EHR.  I had it working several months ago, but when I tried it this eve I noticed the application froze when I tried to get the access token.  it appears that the token part of the OAuth2 exchange has changed and now looks like this:

POST https://api.xxxxxx.com/oauth2/access_token

curl -X POST https://api.xxxxxx.com/oauth2/access_token \
-H 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOnNlY3JldA==' \  //dummy auth
--data "code=a14d2c8e-9c8a-4820-8ae1-d9313bb6abe2&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI" //dummy code

I was going to include a pic of their documentation concerning this, but its copyrighted.  Basically this is what must be included in the post to the token URL:

The Authorization header is required and must be in the format API_KEY:SECRET_KEY and then url safe base64 encoded.
The body of the request must include the following fields:
code - The authorization code that was sent to your Redirect URI at the end of the OAuth login process (see above).
grant_type  - The type of authorization grant in use. In this case code for the authorization code.
redirect_uri - The redirect URI for the application, URL encoded.

Any idea of how to do this in Paw would be greatly appreciated!  Right now the only way I can figure it to do each call manually as a request and pass along the pertinent items.

thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see here, it should be nicely supported by Paw. Here's an example config that should fit your needs:

[image]

In Paw, if you **do NOT** check "Set client credentials in the body", it will set the Client Key and Secret in the `Authorization` header exactly as you described (base64, separated by a `:`, that's the Basic Auth format).

Otherwise, things should be working ok. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  It was working fine before and suddenly it wasn't so I was trying to find the issue.  Turns out I missed an email where they reset everyone's password when they revamped their system recently.  I fixed that and it works like a charm!

Thanks again!